# dotnet core deploying from cmdline using pubxml file

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, msbuild, web-deployment

There is one unique situation we have where we need to manually deploy Asp.Net Core 3.1 code.  I have set up locally some *.pubxml files (like DevProfile.pubxml) with the correct settings for the different environments. They work perfectly when run from VS2019, but how can they be used in a batch file?  The following does not do much of anything when run from the folder that contains the solution file:

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=DevProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `dotnet build WebApplication.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<FolderProfileName>`

Please let me know if this works for you, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#publish-profiles for some more detailed explanations